# Android progress bar doesn't update

Tags: android, file-upload, progress-bar

I'm stuck with a problem with a progress bar. I've created a class which upload a file to an FTP server, the code works correctly but when I tried to implement the progress bar it doesn't update, it jumps from 0% to 100% when the upload is completed.
this is my class:

```
class Upload extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FTPClient client= new FTPClient();
        try {
                InetAddress indirizzo = InetAddress.getByName("myurl.com");
                client.connect(indirizzo);
                //risposta.setText(client.getReplyString());
                //aperta la connessione al server procedo al login
                boolean loggato=client.login("username", "password");
                //if(loggato==true) risposta.append(" ....login effettuato");
                //else risposta.append("...login fallito");
                client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                //apro il file contenuto nel path /sdcard come stream
                client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); // imposto il tipo di dati, da modificare a seconda dell'utilità
                File sdcardDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); //dato che il mio file era sulla sd prendo il riferimento alla memoria       esterna
                File file = new File(sdcardDir,"fotografia.jpg"); //prendo il riferimento al file salvato sulla sd
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);//creo uno stream in input a partire dal mio file
                long lengthofFile = file.length();
                //risposta.append("...path file: " + file.getPath()); //questa istruzione la usavo per test, la lascio casomai dovesse servire, stampa semplicemente il path del file che voglio uploadare

                boolean upload_ok=client.storeFile("fotografia.jpg", fis);
                int progress = 0;
                int bytesRead = 0;
                byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
                BufferedInputStream bufInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                while ((bytesRead = bufInput.read(buf)) != -1) {
                  progress += bytesRead;
                  publishProgress("" + (int) ((progress * 100) / lengthofFile));
                }
                fis.close();//procedo alla chiusura dello stream, infatti storeFile non chiude fis


                } catch (SocketException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_UPLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_UPLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", values[0]);
        progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
    }

}
```

EDIT:

03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976): Process: com.example.downloadingprogressbar, PID: 13976
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "0.0"
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976):    at com.example.downloadingprogressbar.MainActivity$Upload.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:142)
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976):    at com.example.downloadingprogressbar.MainActivity$Upload.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:1)
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:648)
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-02 17:44:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(13976):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not dividing the numbers properly here:

```
publishProgress("" + (int) ((progress * 100) / lengthofFile));
```

You are using int, so when progress is, say, 1024 bytes and the total length is 4096, the result is 0. Try using float instead.

EDIT:
I'd try something like this:

```
...
publishProgress((int) (((float)progress * (float)100) / (float)lengthofFile));
...
```

Also I think you can avoid unnecessary int -> String -> int. Instead, you could declare your class like this:

```
class Upload extends AsyncTask<String, int, String> {
```

then

```
publishProgress((int) (((float)progress * (float)100) / (float)lengthofFile));
```

and finally

```
progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
```

Comment: I changed int to float but now it give me this error (check edit answer)when the upload is completed, and the progress bar still not update.

Comment: That seems to be because you are still using Integer.parseInt in your last method.

Comment: I can't change<String,String,String> to <String,int,String> because it says "Syntax error on token int, Dimension expected after this token"

Comment: Maybe Integer then? and don't forget to change the type in onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) too

Comment: I tried with integer, changed the type onProgressBar, but it still not update.  But now I can't see 100% at the end, it is stuck at 0%